# How to create a simple timeline plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, timeline

I am trying to create a timeline in python. However, I've never done this before and searching for answers haven't helped me much so far.

Basically, I am trying to recreate something similar to the image posted below.

Does anyone have any relevant sources they could provide that would help with this? Alternatively, does anyone know how to code something similar to what is shown in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is what can be done with matplotlib `annotate` + `text`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

xvalues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
xlabels = [r'$t_0 = 2019$', r'$t_0 = 2023$', r'$t_0 = 2048$', r'$t_0 = 2059$', r'$t_0 = 2060$', r'$t_0 = 2066$']
tickheight = 0.1

ax.annotate("", (4, 1), (5, 1), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<-', 'shrinkA': 0, 'shrinkB': 0})
ax.plot([4, 4], [1 - tickheight, 1 + tickheight], c='k', lw=1)
ax.plot([5, 5], [1 - tickheight, 1 + tickheight], c='k', lw=1)
ax.text(4.5, 1.1, 'outflow', ha='center', va='baseline')

ax.annotate("", (2, 2), (4, 2), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<-', 'shrinkA': 0, 'shrinkB': 0})
ax.plot([2, 2], [2 - tickheight, 2 + tickheight], c='k', lw=1)
ax.plot([4, 4], [2 - tickheight, 2 + tickheight], c='k', lw=1)
ax.text(3, 2.1, 'cancelling', ha='center', va='baseline')

ax.annotate("", (1, 3), (3, 3), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<-', 'shrinkA': 0, 'shrinkB': 0})
ax.plot([1, 1], [3 - tickheight, 3 + tickheight], c='k', lw=1)
ax.plot([3, 3], [3 - tickheight, 3 + tickheight], c='k', lw=1)
ax.text(2, 3.1, 'inflow', ha='center', va='baseline')

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax.set_xticks(xvalues)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)

plt.xlim(-0.1, 5.1)
plt.ylim(0, 3.5)

plt.yticks([])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Result looks like this:

[image: Result looks like this]